# how to get the coordinates of a cell using onclick event using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the coordinates of my cells in this table, but with the code i have the coordinates will repeat after each tr tag is closed, so only going from 0-9 (i have a table of 9 rows with 9 cells).
How can i get it to continue instead of starting over? or better yet, is there a way to get x and y coordinates? 
p.s. i have never used jquery.
Thanks.

html code.

```
<table id="grid">
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">1</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">4</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">8</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">9</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">7</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">3</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">4</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">1</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">2</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">9</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">5</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">7</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">1</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">2</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">6</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">5</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">7</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">3</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">6</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">9</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">5</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">7</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">9</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">1</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">4</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">6</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">2</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">3</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">8</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">5</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">1</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">2</td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)"></td>
    <td onclick="myFunction(this)">4</td>
</tr>
```

JScde.js

```
window.onload = function(){

var cells = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
for(var prop in cells){
    if(cells[prop].innerHTML === ''){
        cells[prop].innerHTML += '<input type="text" maxlength="1"/>'
    }
}
};
function myFunction(x){
alert("cell index is: " + x.cellIndex);
```

}

Comment: `tr` elements have [rowIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) property, you can use that as a "y-coordinate".

Comment: Why not try something like this `x.getBoundingClientRect()` that has the x, y, width, and height properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, instead of passing `this` in function callback you should pass `event` and you can use `cellIndex` property of `td` and rowIndex property of `tr` to know the actual coordinates in you terms -

```js
function myFunction(evt){
  let row = evt.target.parentElement.rowIndex;
  let col = evt.target.cellIndex;

  console.log(row, col);
}

let myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
let tds = myTable.querySelectorAll('td');

tds.forEach(function(td){
  td.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>8</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>   
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>8</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>9</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>7</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
```

Live in action - https://jsitor.com/XljAwX0j3

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what i was waiting to do. Also, just for my own learning, is there a way to use JS to avoid having to add the onclick event to all td tags?

Comment: Yes there is. Let me add that in answer.

Comment: I have added JS logic to add click listener on all `td` at once. Enjoy !! :)

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate your help!!